# Write C statement that clears two bits without disturbing the other bits

Tags: c, operators, bit-manipulation, bit

My assignment is to write one or more C statements that clears  (i.e. sets to 0) bits 11 and 12 of the variable "x" without disturbing the other bits using bit-level C-operators. My professor says: "The variable "mask", declared below, may be helpful."

```
int mask = 0x00001800;

int x = arbitrary_value;
```

Should I be using shift operations combined with bit-level operations? I'm a bit unclear how to make this happen.

Comment: Think about the available bitwise operators and what they do.

Comment: From class, I remember we covered &, |, ~, and ^. I'll look over them again.

Comment: `x = (x | mask) ^ mask;` is one way that does not depend on `x` being an `int` or narrower.  Works even if `x` is much wider than `mask`.

Answer (score 2):

@Garrett,
To force or mask some values you will use the **bitwise** operands (&, |, ~, ^).
How to do it is up to you. You can create a mask, like that one you created 0x00001800. If you convert this mask to binary you get this: ‭1100000000000‬. As you can see starting from the right the bits 11 and 12 are the only ones that stay high.

Now, to use this mask to mask a value you need to know what you want to do. For your case you want to force bits 11 and 12 of another variable to 0, so, to force something to 0 you can use the AND bitwise operand (&) passing 0 where you want to force 0 and 1 where you want to stay exactly how it is on the other variable.
If you want to use the mask 0x1800 for this operation you must first invert all his bits, because you want 0s right where this mask has 1s and 1s right where it has 0s. To invert all the bits you can use NOT bitwise operand, like:

```
int mask = 0x1800;
int invertedMask = ~mask;
```

Value of variables in binary:

mask               = 1100000000000
invertedMask  = 0011111111111

Now you can force the bits 11 and 12 from a variable to zero, for example:

```
int mask = 0x1800; //Value in binary 1100000000000
int value = ‭7347‬;   //Value in binary 1110010110011
int finalValue = 0;

mask = ~mask; // Now mask value is 0011111111111
finalValue = value&mask; //final value is 0010010110011
```

As you can see, bits 11 and 12 (from right to left) were forced down while other stay right as in **value** variable.

And using this principles you can use a lot of other combination, including **shift** of bits to deslocate the bits of your mask for example.

Comment: Presenting a detailled solution to a homework assignment will do the OP no favor...

Comment: Would the expression x & 0x7FF work? Doesn't 0011111111111 = 7FF in hexadecimal?

Comment: @chux, thanks i made a mistake. I would use 255 and I changed my mind to use 7347, so I updated the binary but not the int value, haha.

Comment: @GarrettMcClure yes! Perfectly. When you do the NOT bitwise operand with 0x1800 it turns in 0x07ff.

Comment: @Herb, thanks for your care. I guess this's not his entire homework, sometimes it's necessary to show how is the commom way to use operands in a specific language. As you can see by his comment, he's questioning and grabbing the way.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a paper or open the editor of your choice, and re-write the mask's hex notation in binary.

Noticed which bits are set?

Now you need to combine some Boolean operations to actually clear these bits in x. Hint: You need 2 of the basic operations detailled here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Operations

Be careful to ensure, that each possible input is covered, i.e.:

```
00 -> 00
01 -> 00
10 -> 00
11 -> 00
```